# Crear elemento con campos ocultos en el formulario de filament

Tags: laravel-filament, filamentphp

Hola a todos¡¡ Llevo unos dias mirando el uso de filament, tiene mucho potencia. Mi problema, es en mi modelo Leads, que los crea el usuario logeado, tengo un campo user_id que corresponde con el usuario logeado Auth::user()->id. En otros proyectos de laravel no habia problema, lo declaraba y al guardar en el controlador le metia el user_id. Con filament, no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, ya que al generar el recurso leads tengo que introducir o seleccionar el id del usuario, pero no tiene sentido ya que los usuarios logeados no deben seleccionar el id, su id.
¿teneis idea de como se hace? he revisado la doc de filametn pero no encuentro la forma.
Saludos.

He intentado de todo y el error que me da es
`General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: se mas concreto

Comment: Claro, lo siento. 
La idea es guardar desde el formulario "nuevo lead" el user_>id autenticado, que es quien lo crea. En estructura normal de laravel guardaria con save desde el controlador todos los request de los valores del formulario y en el campo user_id el auth()->id, pero no lo puedo hacer en filament, he probado de todo.

Answer (score -1):

```
use Filament\Forms\Components\Hidden;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Hidden::make("user_id")
 ->default(Auth::user()->id),
```

Comment: eso que hace? cómo resuelve el problema?

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/396281)